# Author page like wordpress answers

Tags: pages, users

I'm newbie in wordpress. I want to implement a page like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users
But no idea how to implement. The user listing, info, avatar,user search everything will same. any idea about the issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Members List Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-list/)

> The Members Plugin allows you to create a post on your wordpress blog that lists all your wordpress members. When viewing the list of members you can also search through your members according to first name, last name, email address, URL or any other number of user meta fields you may specify. Employing pagination you can page through your search results and sort your results according to last name, first name, registration date, email or any other field you may specify

I'm currently using it in a project and it works great.

Comment: I dont know how to thank you. It's exactly what i looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if it answers your question , just accept this as the right answer, Glad i could help.\